How come the light bends from the side wall and reach eye?
When you stand in front of a railway tunnel or a long pipe that's completely straight and is in uniform height. Why do we see the other end? Shouldn't it be hidden behind the front-most surface?
P.S- Lets say a pipe can be imagined as a series of rings stacked on top of each other. If we look through the pipe, we can only see the rings that are directly in line with our sight. The rings that are behind other rings are blocked from our view. So when we see a pipe we should rather see a single circle

Why would it be hidden?

Lets say a pipe can be imagined as a series of rings stacked on top of each other. If we look through the pipe, we can only see the rings that are directly in line with our sight. The rings that are behind other rings are blocked from our view. So when we see a pipe we should rather see a single  circle.

Suppose one of your eyes is on the axis of the pipe, then of course the light reflected by the internal surface (that's what you really see, and it will not be blocked if your eyes are at a proper position) of each ring can directly travel in to your eye. If you don't mind to draw a simplest optical path picture you would easily notice that.
I guess this question came out because you don't really understand how we human sense the "size" of objects we see. Actually, when we look at something, instead of its real geometry size, we sense its visual angle. The circle on the other end is much farther so its visual angle is also smaller, and that's why the other end would often seem smaller then this end.
